# How to change color of this icon?

Tags: gimp, logo, icon, color-conversion

[image]I've read several tutorials and watched quite a few videos but none of them are working.

I am using GIMP and wanting to change color of this icon to the following hex color.

Hex color - #006b5f

The logo I have attached, can someone please, please help me. I am needing to get this sorted asap and have been trying since Thursday last week, to get this done and it's giving me a huge headache, that something so simple, is becoming an absolute nightmare to sort.

Answer (score 8):

1. Click on the Foreground colour square in the toolbar, and enter the colour as shown here, and click OK.

[image]

2. In the layers panel hit the Alpha Lock button

[image]

3. Do *Edit > Fill with FG colour*

[image]

That's it really!  Do *File > Export as*, and save as PNG. Make sure to use a new file name so you don't overwrite the original.

Comment: Thanks a lot for leaving a step by step and as simple as it looks, I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my GIMP, as I followed your instructions step by step and it does not work. This is becoming very frustrating for me, that I just do not understand why this is happening.

Comment: @JamesGoodman Which step are you having trouble with?